# flutter doesn't see the json file

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I was making an application and encountered such an error and the application was working a day ago.
my app works with the google drive api, perhaps because of this errors appear
I've restarted the app, changed the path, and more
I am new to flutter, I will be glad of any help, thanks in advance

```
Restarted application in 1 591ms.
E/flutter ( 5401): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PathNotFoundException: Cannot open file, path = 'lib/allSchools/schedule11b-9a0bedcbbb69.json' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)
E/flutter ( 5401): #0      _checkForErrorResponse (dart:io/common.dart:55:9)
E/flutter ( 5401): #1      _File.open.<anonymous closure> (dart:io/file_impl.dart:381:7)
E/flutter ( 5401): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5401): #2      _File.readAsString (dart:io/file_impl.dart:621:18)
E/flutter ( 5401): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5401): #3      getAllschool
allSchool.dart:15
E/flutter ( 5401): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5401):`your text'
```

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:googleapis/drive/v3.dart' as drive;
import 'package:googleapis_auth/auth.dart' as auth;
import 'package:googleapis_auth/auth_io.dart' as auth_io;
import 'package:path/path.dart' as path;

Future<void> getAllschool() async {
  final credentialsFileName = 'schedule11b-9a0bedcbbb69.json';
  final credentialsFilePath = path.join(
      'lib','allSchools',credentialsFileName);

  final credentialsFile = File(credentialsFilePath);
  final credentials = auth.ServiceAccountCredentials.fromJson(
      await credentialsFile.readAsString());

  final client = await auth_io.clientViaServiceAccount(
      credentials, [drive.DriveApi.driveScope]);

  final driveApi = drive.DriveApi(client);

  final folderId = '1N8TZ4e6d9sQeU35VRlFJxFDUpIIxBNnu';

  final files = await driveApi.files.list(q: "'$folderId' in parents");

  if (files.files != null) {
    for (var file in files.files!) {
      print('File name: ${file.name}');
    }
  } else {
    print('Files not found.');
  }

  client.close();
}
```

Comment: The credentials file should probably be in a folder under /assets and that folder should be listed in the assets: section of your pubspec.yaml file.  Learn more at https://fluttertalk.com/flutter-read-json-file-from-assets/